# Can someone help me? My switch statement in javascript file is not working but when I turn it to if statement it works well. How can I fix this?

Tags: javascript

Can someone help me? My switch statement in javascript file is not working but when I turn it to if statement it works well. How can I fix this?

```
 function validate()
    {
         switch (document.getElementById("choose").value)
            {
                case 0:
                    var ucompare=new RegExp(/^[\S][a-zA-Z ]{1,}$/g);
                    var pcompare=new RegExp(/^(("[\w-+\s]+")|([\w-+]+(?:\.[\w-+]+)*)|("[\w-+\s]+")([\w-+]+(?:\.[\w-+]+)*))(@((?:[\w-+]+\.)*\w[\w-+]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][\d]\.|1[\d]{2}\.|[\d]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][\d]|1[\d]{2}|[\d]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][\d]|1[\d]{2}|[\d]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
                    var user=true,pass=true;
                    var uname=document.getElementById("username").value;
                    var pword=document.getElementById("password").value;
                    if(ucompare.test(uname)==false)
                    {
                        user=false;
                    }
                    if(pcompare.test(pword)==false)
                    {
                        pass=false;
                    }
                    if(user==false&&pass==true)
                    {
                        alert("Invalid ID number. Please enter a valid family name.");
                    }
                    else if(user==true&&pass==false)
                    {
                        alert("Invalid password. Please enter a valid e-mail address.");
                    }
                    else if(user==false&&pass==false)
                    {
                        alert("Invalid inputs. Please enter a valid family name as ID number and a valid e-mail address as password."); 
                    }
                    break;
            }
    }
```

any ideas?

Comment: What does "not working" mean? What is the expected behaviour? What is the actual behaviour? Any errors in the console? (Why do you have a switch with only one case? Why are you calling `new RegExp()` with arguments that are already regex objects?)

Comment: A value is always a string, it's never the number `0`? In the `if` statement you're probably  using non-strict comparison

Comment: Thank you adeneo! solved my problem

Comment: Try making a fiddle and adding a default to the switch statement

Answer (score 0):

Put quotes around the 0 in your case statement.
You should however just use an if statement.